# Are there standard shortcuts on Android?

Tags: android, menu

Is there any kind of guide about shortcuts in Android? I have the typical CRUD and I want to assign familiar shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I checked, the answer was **no**.

Answer (score 8):

```
Switch between applications / quick launch:
Browser SEARCH + b
Contacts SEARCH + c
E-Mail SEARCH + e
Google Mail SEARCH + g
Calendar SEARCH + l
Maps SEARCH + m
Music SEARCH + p
Messaging SEARCH + s
YouTube SEARCH + y

Navigation within lists
Page down SPACEBAR
Page up SHIFT + SPACEBAR
Jump to end of list ALT + TRACKBALL roll DOWN
Jump to top of list ALT + TRACKBALL roll UP

Typing and text navigation tips:
Insert special character ALT + SPACEBAR opens special character selector
Delete character to left DEL
Delete character to right SHIFT + DEL
Delete entire line ALT + DEL
Persistent CAPS Press SHIFT twice; press SHIFT again to escape
Jump cursor to beginning/end of line ALT + roll TRACKBALL left/right
Create tab character ALT + q
Highlight (select) text SHIFT + roll TRACKBALL
Cut text MENU + x, or Highlight text, press & hold TRACKBALL, select Cut
Copy text to clipboard MENU + c, or Highlight text, press & hold
TRACKBALL, select Copy
Paste text copied to clipboard MENU + v, or Highlight text, press & hold
TRACKBALL, select Paste
Undo change MENU + z
Select all text in field MENU + a, or Highlight text, press & hold
TRACKBALL, select Select all

Browser shortcuts
Open Go to window MENU + s
Open Bookmarks MENU + b
Open Windows MENU + w
View history MENU + h
Refresh or stop page MENU + r
Go back a page MENU + j
Go forward a page MENU + k
Find on page MENU + f
Go to home page MENU + ENTER
Zoom in MENU + i
Zoom out MENU + o
Go to Settings MENU + p
Page down SPACEBAR
Page up SHIFT + SPACEBAR

Map shortcuts
Directions MENU + d
Select map mode MENU + m
History MENU + h
My Location MENU + 0 (zero)
Go to Settings MENU + p
Zoom in MENU + i
Zoom out MENU + o
```

Comment: I was more looking into something like:

add an item in any application: 'a' and '1' (there are number shortcuts), delete an item anywhere: 'd' and '7', etc.

Thanks.